# Hadoop DistributedCache classpath resolution

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am facing an issue using a Hadoop's DistributedCache. I am getting  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException for the jars which were successfully added to cache. 
I revealed the problem:
- The client is running on Windows machine and seems that mapred.job.classpath.archives are resolved on client side. Since the classpath is OS dependant I am getting evaluated to:

mapred.job.classpath.archives   /distcache/MinuteCheckMetrics-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;/distcache/HBaseSchema-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;

Where ; is not valid on Unix hence the class is not found.

Is there any setting on client side (DistributedManager, Configuration etc.) which would solve this and make client independent?

I am using hadoop 1.0.4. and DistributedCache.addArchiveToClassPath()
Thanks for helping me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is reported https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-9123

Quick resolution can be: java.lang.System.setProperty("path.separator", ":");